# Why would you use a generic type specifier when extending a Java class?

Tags: java, generics

I just wonder what usage the following code has:

```
public class Sub extends java.util.ArrayList<String> {...}
```

There is no any compiling restriction on the generic constraint `java.util.ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: What do you mean, "There is no any compiling restriction on the generic constraint java.util.ArrayList<String>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you were making an index for a book, but you don't know how many indices you will need. You could make a class `BookIndex extends ArrayList<String>` or if you want to get really picky: `BookIndex extends ArrayList<IndexEntry>`.

/e1
Also, when a one Class extends a generic Class like `ArrayList<String>` you **can** grab the `String` out from the generic declaration, unlike if you had a class `ArrayList<T>`. In `ArrayList<T>` you would never be able to figure out what the `T` is.

Comment: I don't think inheritance is the right way to make an index for a book. Better USE an array/arraylist than extending from it.

Comment: It's not the best way to do this, but it is a way.

Comment: +1 Good point; it's generally better to [prefer composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does place restrictions on other code based on the type parameter in this case.

This will compile

```
public class Sub extends java.util.ArrayList<String> {
  void addTwice(String s) { this.add(s); this.add(s); }
}
```

but this will not

```
public class Sub extends java.util.ArrayList<String> {
  void addTwice(Object x) { this.add(x); this.add(x); }
}
```

Comment: Remember, It is not a good practise to extend standard class. Instead, you write them inside a class and use them. Check my answer

Comment: @saugok, I did not forget that.  I just answered the OP's question which I assumed was simplified to use a standard class to use a short example instead of defining two classes.

Comment: @saugok, Besides, your rule is overly broad.  Some standard classes are meant to be overridden, e.g. `FilterInputStream`.

Comment: @Smauel, I had better revise my demo code from `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<TString>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend class `ArrayList`, but it is not something that you should normally do.
Only ever say "`extends`" when you can truthfully say "`this class IS-A that class.`"

Remember, *Its not a good practise **to extend** the standard classes*

Why not use like this ?

```
public class Sub {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    // .. 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it a good practice? Isn't this what an Object Oriented language is for? I think it really depends on what you want/need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you do that you can add to the basic functionality of an `ArrayList` or even change its normal functionality.

For example, you can override the `add()` method so that it will only add emails to the list.